# How to change Day of Week abbreviation in Android Datepicker?

Tags: java, android, datetime

I wish to change the abbreviation of day of week in our Datepicker dialogue. For the Locale Spanish, I'm getting the following abbreviations for Day of the week: L M X J V S D.
I wish to change this to reflect it as : L M M J V S D.
Does anyone have an idea on how this can be changed? I only need to change this for when my locale becomes Spanish.
[image]

Edit: Declaration and use of Datepicker-

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day+1);

dialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,getString(R.string.ok),dialog);

dialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,getString(R.string.dismiss),dialog);
```

Comment: could you please show how you're creating this dialog ?

Comment: add it to your question as text, not as a comment please

Comment: @a_local_nobody Made the edits as required.